# Does the PF Servo motor return to center?

Tags: power-functions, motor

Does the PF Servo motor, which was introduced in the [9398: 4x4 Crawler model](http://brickset.com/detail/?Set=9398-1), have return to center feature?

Answer (score 5):

Here is another video from Sariel which shows that it returns to center: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_Gvuzsngg8

- With the [58122c01 Remote Control Unit](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=58122c01) it returns to center if the remote is not actuated.
- With the [64227 IR Speed Remote Control Unit](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=64227)  it returns to central position when the stop button is pressed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does, see http://technicbricks.blogspot.fr/2012/06/pf-servo-in-action.html